# TableView with fix first column and rest columns scrollable Android

Tags: android, tableview, scrollable-table

I have a problem. in my situation I have tables with 10+ columns, I really need to have a horizontal scroll for it and also making more width for each column. And fix the first column like excel. is there anyway to do that?

Please let me know any simple and smooth library in android for the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView) Library for Android. It's also open source and located in github.

There is a sample app that show how you can use tableView on your application.